# Take Screenshot using AShot and Watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, jruby, ashot

I am trying to use AShot with Selenium to take a screenshot.

```
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'javalib/ashot-1.5.4.jar'

driver_path = 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\chromedriver\tools\chromedriver.exe'
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = driver_path

base_url = 'https://www.google.com/'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to base_url

ashot = Java::RuYandexQatoolsAshot::AShot.new
png = ashot.takeScreenshot(driver)

test_pod_name = 'c:\data\google_screenshot.png'
File.write(test_pod_name, png)
puts "Writing to: #{test_pod_name}"

driver.close
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
Unhandled Java exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
            getDeclaredMethods0 at java/lang/Class.java:-2
      privateGetDeclaredMethods at java/lang/Class.java:2729
             getDeclaredMethods at java/lang/Class.java:2003
                   computeValue at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/Initializer.java:467
                   computeValue at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/Initializer.java:464
                 getFromHashMap at java/lang/ClassValue.java:227
                  getFromBackup at java/lang/ClassValue.java:209
                            get at java/lang/ClassValue.java:115
                     getMethods at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/Initializer.java:498
              setupClassMethods at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/ClassInitializer.java:116
                     initialize at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/ClassInitializer.java:31
                setupProxyClass at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/Initializer.java:100
               createProxyClass at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:528
             generateClassProxy at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:486
       createProxyClassForClass at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:442
                   computeValue at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaSupportImpl.java:126
                   computeValue at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaSupportImpl.java:118
                            get at org/jruby/util/collections/MapBasedClassValue.java:25
         getProxyClassFromCache at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaSupportImpl.java:199
                  getProxyClass at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:409
                  getProxyClass at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:402
            getProxyClassOrNull at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:976
            getProxyClassOrNull at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:927
  getProxyOrPackageUnderPackage at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:885
     relativeJavaClassOrPackage at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaPackage.java:188
                  const_missing at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaPackage.java:127
                           call at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaPackage$INVOKER$i$1$0$const_missing.gen:-1
                        finvoke at org/jruby/RubyClass.java:909
                         invoke at org/jruby/runtime/Helpers.java:442
                     callMethod at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:363
           searchModuleForConst at org/jruby/ir/targets/ConstantLookupSite.java:133
                         <main> at C:/src/energyflow/exdb/data/netlogix/scripts/google-screenshot-selenium.rb:12
            invokeWithArguments at java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.java:627
                           load at org/jruby/ir/Compiler.java:94
                      runScript at org/jruby/Ruby.java:830
                    runNormally at org/jruby/Ruby.java:749
                    runNormally at org/jruby/Ruby.java:767
                    runFromMain at org/jruby/Ruby.java:580
                  doRunFromMain at org/jruby/Main.java:417
                    internalRun at org/jruby/Main.java:305
                            run at org/jruby/Main.java:232
                           main at org/jruby/Main.java:204

Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
                      findClass at java/net/URLClassLoader.java:382
                      loadClass at java/lang/ClassLoader.java:418
                      loadClass at java/lang/ClassLoader.java:351
            getDeclaredMethods0 at java/lang/Class.java:-2
      privateGetDeclaredMethods at java/lang/Class.java:2729
             getDeclaredMethods at java/lang/Class.java:2003
                   computeValue at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/Initializer.java:467
                   computeValue at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/Initializer.java:464
                 getFromHashMap at java/lang/ClassValue.java:227
                  getFromBackup at java/lang/ClassValue.java:209
                            get at java/lang/ClassValue.java:115
                     getMethods at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/Initializer.java:498
              setupClassMethods at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/ClassInitializer.java:116
                     initialize at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/ClassInitializer.java:31
                setupProxyClass at org/jruby/javasupport/binding/Initializer.java:100
               createProxyClass at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:528
             generateClassProxy at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:486
       createProxyClassForClass at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:442
                   computeValue at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaSupportImpl.java:126
                   computeValue at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaSupportImpl.java:118
                            get at org/jruby/util/collections/MapBasedClassValue.java:25
         getProxyClassFromCache at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaSupportImpl.java:199
                  getProxyClass at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:409
                  getProxyClass at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:402
            getProxyClassOrNull at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:976
            getProxyClassOrNull at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:927
  getProxyOrPackageUnderPackage at org/jruby/javasupport/Java.java:885
     relativeJavaClassOrPackage at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaPackage.java:188
                  const_missing at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaPackage.java:127
                           call at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaPackage$INVOKER$i$1$0$const_missing.gen:-1
                        finvoke at org/jruby/RubyClass.java:909
                         invoke at org/jruby/runtime/Helpers.java:442
                     callMethod at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:363
           searchModuleForConst at org/jruby/ir/targets/ConstantLookupSite.java:133
                         <main> at C:/src/energyflow/exdb/data/netlogix/scripts/google-screenshot-selenium.rb:12
            invokeWithArguments at java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.java:627
                           load at org/jruby/ir/Compiler.java:94
                      runScript at org/jruby/Ruby.java:830
                    runNormally at org/jruby/Ruby.java:749
                    runNormally at org/jruby/Ruby.java:767
                    runFromMain at org/jruby/Ruby.java:580
                  doRunFromMain at org/jruby/Main.java:417
                    internalRun at org/jruby/Main.java:305
                            run at org/jruby/Main.java:232
                           main at org/jruby/Main.java:204
```

It's funny that the error dump doesn't refer to AShot - but the error originates from the line instatiating AShot.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open method in Selenium-webdriver method for capturing screenshots. You can use something like

```
@driver.save_screenshot('c:\data\google_screenshot.png')
```

Comment: Thanks @illakia - I am aware of that.   But I wanted to use ashot because of its ability to capture screen shots for images that are larger than the window size.